# Access main activity from through an app

Tags: android

My app is structured like this

MainActivity --> getToolbar()
fragment a
fragment b : starts GetDetailsActivity

GetDetailsActivity() : needs to call getToolbar()

Fragments a & b are started from Main.
b can start GetDetailsActivity.

How should I pass are reference to MainActivity to GetDetailsActivity in order for GetDetails to call getToolbar

What's the proper way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not pass an activity as a reference to another activity. Each activity should have its own Toolbar as ActionBar, defined in its layout file. Just like you have a toolbar in MainActivity's XML layout, you should have another one for DetailsActivity's XML layout.

Comment: This is correct. You should have independent Toolbars for each layout.